# How to Concat String in LINQ SQL WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I want to concat the where in linq, but I can't find the answer in the net, so ask in this site. this is my problem.

in mysql:

> select * from table where concat(field1, ' ', field2) = 'field1
>   field2';

how can I convert it in linq sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to easily accomplish this in the following manner (I'm using the NorthWind database and fluent Linq-to-SQL):

```
Employees.Where (e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName == "Nancy Davolio")
```

Comment: who is Nancy Davolio?

Comment: Your question makes me laugh -- Nancy Davolio is not a real person as far as I know but she's been in the Northwind sample database for a LONG time.  I laugh because her name is almost like computer lingo of a sort to me.  Same with Albert Futerkist...same reason.

Comment: I though she is your lover. Thank you for your trivia. I learned something new instead of my question.

Comment: https://twitter.com/nancydavolio?lang=en

Comment: @rmed1na Thank you for that!  I get to enjoy a little laugh about this thread again today, 7 years later.

Answer (score 0):

```
string x = "field1 field2";

List<Tuple<string, string>> tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("field1", "field2"));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("field1", "field3"));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("field1", "field4"));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("field1", "field5"));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("field1", "field6"));
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("field1", "field2"));

var results = tupleList.Where(l => String.Concat(l.Item1, " ", l.Item2) == x);

results.Dump();
```